# Ado Entity Data Model add tables from diffrent schema

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

i have the ADO/net Entity Data Model with Oracle for .net4 with vs 2010, i am using userdId1 to for connection string which has the read/write  access to schema for userId2 tables. i need to add the tables from userId2 to my edmx file, but since i am connecting using userid1 , the tables for userdid2 is not displayed.
is there any way i could use tables from different schema in ADO.net EDM?

Comment: I am using EF 4.2, see my answer on this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422275/oracle-entity-framework-generate-entity-from-tables-in-different-schema/8537963#8537963

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly all tables in a model use the same connection string.

Ways to get around it are:

- give userid1 rights to userid2 tables
- create a view and give userid1 access to the view

Comment: only other way is to create seperate dbcontexts and map them seperately