# Oracle Entity Framework - Generate Entity From Tables in Different Schema

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I log into Oracle using my own user account, which we can call **my_account**, and I am granted *select* privileges on all of the tables in the schema that our application uses, which I will call **app_schema**.

I would like to use Entity Manager to generate the entity definitions for the tables in the **app_schema** schema, but I do not have the password for that account and likely won't be given it, so I must log in as **my_account**.

When I run the wizard I can only see the tables in the **my_account** schema. Is there any way to get the tables from a different schema so that I can generate those? This is a massive database, so writing the .edmx file by hand could take days, and will probably result in tons of typo-induced errors. I have attempted to use synonyms, but they are not visible in the wizard either.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In your Server explorer, select your connection and right.
Click on filters tab, select Displayed schemas, then add more schemas from your schemas list.
Remember click on update button and Ok to save changes on your connection.

Now when you add a new ADO.Net Entity Data Model you will see all tables from your schemas.

Please visit this link:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2291628&tstart=0

I hope help you with this.

Cesar.

Comment: This saved a lot of time me.

Comment: One of the most under voted helpful answers in SO. Added a screenshot to further depict the process, if you do not mind.

Comment: I reported what seems to be a bug with the proposed solution at oracle forums, [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3946813?sr=inbox). Overall it works.

Comment: Keep the schema of the user in "Displayed schemas" in the list, otherwise the tables won't show up when you want to add a data model

Answer (score 1):

I am using EF 4.2 and found that I was able to use tables from another user/schema only when creating a new connection (using **my_account**) and using a filter when going through the Entity Data Model Wizard. Add **app_schema** to the Displayed Schemas filter (be sure to press Update).

Like CMarchan suggests, if I set the filter on the connection in the server explorer, it works for me there, but the EDM wizard does not see the connection when creating a new model (maybe just a "feature" in 4.2).

Once the EDM is created, it does allow me to add/edit tables from **app_schema**.