# Table List is not showing in Entity Data Model Wizard for Oracle

Tags: c#

Am using VS 2017 and installed Oracle developer tools for VS.
Installed EntityFramework 6 via Nuget.
Installed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework libraries via Nuget.
Add entity data model and Selected EF Designer from Database.
And tested the DB connection and connection is success. After clicking Next Button, Entity Data Model Wizard is simply closed without showing table list.

Can any one help to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downgraded EntityFramework Version from 6.2.0 to Version 5.0.0. After that, I can create .edmx model. Everything is okay now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded EntityFramework Version from 6.2.0 to Version 5.0.0. After that, I can create .edmx model. Everything is okay now.

Answer (score 0):

There could be one more reason why a certain oracle user will not see list of tables after connection. This is when you connect with a Oracle_User account which is different than the Oracle_Owner account under which the required tables actually exists.

In this case:

a) Oracle_User must have the right privs (select, insert, update, delete) on tables in Oracle_owner schema.

b) Next refer to [Oracle Entity Framework - Generate Entity From Tables in Different Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422275/oracle-entity-framework-generate-entity-from-tables-in-different-schema) to see how to import tables from a different schema in the ADO Data Model Wizard using database first approach.

For me, EFv6.4, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v19.6, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFrameWork v19.6 works with oracle 12c (or 12.1) on VS2017.